# pip Installing a python module in Python 3, but that module has a dependency package that requires Python 2

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, pip, python-3.6

so I am new to Python and what is a good way to learn it is to do some personal project :) So I am on my Windows and using `virtualenv` to contain environment

So, I need to use the Scrappy module:

`pip install scrappy`

```
Collecting scrappy
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.4.tar.gz
Collecting guessit (from scrappy)
  Using cached guessit-2.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting tvdb_api (from scrappy)
  Using cached tvdb_api-2.0.tar.gz
Collecting hachoir-metadata (from scrappy)
  Using cached hachoir-metadata-1.3.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USERPH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-__zp7zbj\hachoir-metadata\setup.py", line 65
        except OSError, err:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USERPH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-__zp7zbj\h
achoir-metadata\
```

Its because `hachoir-metadata` is a Python2 dependent package, so I tried installing their Python 3 version

`pip install hachoir3`

I confirmed that it was installed using

`pip list | Select-String hachoir3`

so I tried running

`pip install scrappy` again

but same error.

Any work around to install scrappy? I cannot go down to Python 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scrappy` itself [contains code](https://github.com/louist87/Scrappy/blob/56c322249a0ecd1601f05ef822739cf97e37edc6/scrappy/core.py#L100) that only works in Python 2. I.e. `Scrappy` cannot be used with Python 3+.

Comment: ended up using conda, and use the Scrapy they have in their conda-forge channel. Thanks!